# ngRoute in AngularJS not routing to ashx file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to route a link to a `.ashx` service file, but it's not working. It works fine when I redirect to `.html` files, but when I redirect it to an `.ashx`, file it gives an error; file does not exist on current directory.

The following is my `App.config` code:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            controller: "homeController",
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
        })
        .when("/api", {
            controller: "apiController",
            templateUrl: "../ExclusiveAutoSales_Handler.ashx",
        })
        .when("/filter", {
            controller: "filterController",
            templateUrl: "templates/filter.html",
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/home"
        })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: script file is in this (Angularapp/js/script.js) directory
html files are in this (Angularapp/templates/home.html) directory 
and .ashx file is in (Angularapp/ExclusiveAutoSales_Handler.ashx) directory

Comment: You should put the ashx in an html file then route to that html file with angular